# On set of all $Z$-module homomorphisms as injective module

Tags: modules, injective-module, divisible-groups

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the integers.

The set $M$ of all $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms from a ring $R$ with unity to a divisible abelian group $A$ is known to be an injective left $R$-module.

I am wondering if the word "divisible" for $A$ dropped, is $M$ still injective? Is there any concrete example or source for me to read to find the answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No chance, take $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and consider $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then your $M$ would be $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which is faaaaar from being injective for $n\neq 0,1$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this only one example, or are you implying if $M$ is injective, then $A$ must be divisible? Hence it is a biconditional?

Comment: well, divisible groups are precisely the injective objects for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so as soon as you drop this condition, you immediately get problems in the trivial way by using $\mathbb{Z}$. That is also the whole idea behind the construction you are considering. one wants to use these "standard" injective objects to construct some in the category of $R$-modules and use them to guarantee that the category has enough injectives.
But to relax the divisibility assumptuion you for sure will have to also insert some assumptions on your ring, in particular you need to exclude $\mathbb{Z}$